# Unable to boot into Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, ubuntu-15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 alongside a Windows 10 OS. My issues has nothing to do with the latter btw (I hope).

I had few tutorial videos in the Videos folder in Ubuntu, which I wanted to move to another folder (which I wanted to be at /, called videotutorials (or whatever)). I successfully created the folder, at /, and performed sudo mv to that folder, and the whole computer froze. I left it there for almost half hour, even then, nothing. Then I performed RIESUB on it, after which, every time the computer was booted, it shows

[image]

I have Ubuntu 15.10 alongside a Windows 10 OS. My issues has nothing to do with the latter btw (I hope).

I had few tutorial videos in the Videos folder in Ubuntu, which I wanted to move to another folder (which I wanted to be at /, called videotutorials (or whatever)). I successfully created the folder, at /, and performed sudo mv to that folder, and the whole computer froze. I left it there for almost half hour, even then, nothing. Then I performed RIESUB on it, after which, every time the computer was booted, it shows

If I exit it (by tying exit), it exists and shows

[image]

The only way I can enter Windows is by opting the last option. If I hit the fourth, it just goes back to the first screenshot.

Please can you help?

Comment: You problem is caused by grub not finding the grub.cfg. How exactly did you install it? Through the Ubuntu installer or running `grub-install` manually?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness you have to fix Windows booting and Ubuntu booting.

To fix Windows booting on UEFI (once booted to Windows):

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

This will rewrite Windows boot files.

For fixing Ubuntu booting you need a live CD/DVD/USB. Follow this tutorial:

[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

After that you will have a dual-boot selection over GRUB2 boot menu for Ubuntu or Windows.

Using firmware functionality you can reorder NVRAM boot menu entries and place Windows as first boot candidate, then you will have a dual boot choice only when selecting firmware boot device option. (Windows will boot by default - no boot choice as Windows cannot chain load Ubuntu on UEFI by design)

Comment: I have this:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/15537217/ Will that help?

Comment: He does not need `bcdboot` since he clearly showed/told that Windows boots fine. `bcdboot` should only be used when the Windows Boot Manager / BCD store is gone, otherwise it will cost you the association to the recovery environment for nothing.

Comment: I don't have an SSD! Not that I know of.

Comment: Anonymous - Ok, you don't have SSD, you have an attached USB maybe.

Comment: Tom Yan, you are right, bcdboot does not care about connection for recovery loader. Can be reattached easily using ReAgentC. The question is how would a write to /some_folder change GRUB files? I suspect some other operation involved here.